# Observable breaks the link controller-view

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

I've just faced a weird issue that I was able to solve by replacing an Observable by a Promise. However, I would like to understand what happened there.

I have a function using Observable returning the geolocation (lat/long) of the user. The function itself works fine.
However, after calling this function in app-component.ts its like the link between the controller and the view is broken. Any update controller side is not displayed on the view.

After switching to Promise, everything works as expected and I was able to update my view to display the data.

I got no errors, no warning, nothing.

Here is a sample of what I am doing: https://gist.github.com/Dlacreme/cad5ba878dcacb3916a552dfb684cd1f

(package.json available in Gist)

Thank you!

EDIT:

1. seems like we can't use the object `navigator.geolocation` with stackblitz
2. using `ChangeDetectorRef` will successfully update the view but won't 'rebuild' the link between view and controller (therefore I would need to use it manually anytime I want my view to be updated)

Comment: a stackblitz demo would be much better than gist code

Comment: Ok, let me do that

Comment: when you say `// Everything seems good. But at this point, the view won't be updated anymore.` , you mean the value is not changing in UI. If so, did u try `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. `ChangeDetectorRef`  will update the view but won't 'rebuild' the link between view and controller. I would have to use it everytime I want my view to be updated

Comment: You should move the navigator permission part to parent function, in this case its ngOnit where you will subscribe to coordinate function. If you do that then you dont need ChangeDetectorRef